# GetPixel makes the game slow

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm creating a cleaning game but in the getpixel line of code makes the game slow or having a delay. I need this line of code to detect the remaining dirt. How can I improve the code? or is there other way to detect remaining dirt?

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            if (touch.position != currentPosition || touch.position != prevPosition)
            {
                SetSinglePixel(touch.position);

                prevPosition = touch.position;
            }
                
        }

        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            if (touch.position != currentPosition || touch.position != prevPosition)
            {
                currentPosition = touch.position;

                Vector2 dif = currentPosition - prevPosition;

                float distance = dif.magnitude;

                if (distance > 36)
                {
                    float count = distance / 36;

                    float n = distance / (count + 1);

                    float ddmo = 36;

                    for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
                    {
                        Vector2 gapPoint = Vector2.MoveTowards(prevPosition, currentPosition, ddmo * i);

                        if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(gapPoint), out RaycastHit hit))
                        {
                            gapPositions.Add(hit.textureCoord);
                        }
                    }

                    SetMultiplePixel(gapPositions);

                    gapPositions.Clear();
                }

                else
                {
                    SetSinglePixel(currentPosition);
                }

                prevPosition = touch.position;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void SetMultiplePixel(List<Vector2> givenPoints)
{
    foreach (Vector2 pos in givenPoints)
    {
        SetPixel(pos.x, pos.y);
    }
}

private void SetSinglePixel(Vector2 touchPos)
{
    if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touchPos), out RaycastHit hit))
    {
        SetPixel(hit.textureCoord.x, hit.textureCoord.y);
    }
}

public void ResetTexture()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
}

private void SetPixel(float textureCoordX, float textureCoordY, bool isCheckRemainingTexture = false)
{
    int pixelX = (int)(textureCoordX * _templateDirtMask.width);
    int pixelY = (int)(textureCoordY * _templateDirtMask.height);

    int pixelXOffset = pixelX - (_brush.width / 2);
    int pixelYOffset = pixelY - (_brush.height / 2);

    for (int x = 0; x < _brush.width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < _brush.height; y++)
        {
            data = (pixelXOffset + x) + (pixelYOffset + y) * _templateDirtMask.width;

            if (data > 0 && data < pixels.Length)
            {
                pixelDirt = _brush.GetPixel(x, y);// this code makes the game slow 

                Color pixelDirtMask = _templateDirtMask.GetPixel(pixelXOffset + x, pixelYOffset + y); // this code makes the game slow

                float removedAmount = pixelDirtMask.g - (pixelDirtMask.g * pixelDirt.g);

                dirtAmount -= removedAmount;

                pixels[data] = new Color(0, pixelDirtMask.g * pixelDirt.g, 0);
            }
                
        }
    }

    ApplyTexture();
}
```

Comment: Well. It reads like for every frame make it redraw a frame. Because youre changing whats there.

Comment: Does profiler tell you that line is slow?

Comment: @shingo I tried removing that line and it draws pixel without problem.

Comment: @BugFinder is there anyway to check for remaining dirt without using getpixels?